# Layout Background gets "highligted" (blue) while keyboard is visible

Tags: android, listview, background, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a RelativeLayout on Top that includes EditTexts and a FrameLayout (just as a Frame for the List), that includes itself a ListView. When I click inside a EditText the Background, the FrameLayout as well as all other transparent areas get light blue, as long as the keyboard is active and the EditTexts are empty. When I fill these EditTexts, some undefinable parts of the screen around the EditTexts get their supposed color back. If the EditTexts are already filled when the keyboard shows up, the effect does not appear.

I have spent several hours to investigate in this bug, searching for a hint but still have no clue how to narrow this down. I wish I could give you more information, but I do not know what could be relevant.

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F2F2E5">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/extendedActionBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#d8d8d8" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/verbundenMit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Verbunden mit:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DeviceName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="165dp"
            android:text="Device"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fehlerbezeichnung"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="540dp"
            android:text="Fehlerbezeichnung"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/rand_actionbar" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="740dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Parametersatzvergleich"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="Vergleich:     Online/Offline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NeuParameter"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="Neuer Parametersatz" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filter_bez"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:text="Auswahlkriterien"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/offlineframeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filter_bez"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:background="#d8d8d8" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/offline_parameter_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#FFFCCC"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >
        </ListView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filterParameternummer_bez"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filter_bez"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Parameternr:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/filterParameternummer"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/filterParameternummer_bez"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/filterParameternummer_bez"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:inputType="number" android:hint="...">
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:onClick="search"
        android:text="Auswahl anwenden" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filterInfotext_bez"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Infotext:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filter_bez"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/filterInfotext"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" 
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/filterInfotext_bez"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/filterInfotext_bez" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="320dp" 
        android:hint="..." android:focusable="true" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity

```
public final class OfflineParameterActivity extends AbstractBindingActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private ArrayAdapter<ParameterSet> listAdapter;
    public static final String EXTRA_DB_SOLLWERTE = "SollWerte";
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int REQUEST_PARAMETER_DETAILS = 100;
    private static final int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_ENABLE = 100;
    private static final int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_DEVICES = 101;
    private Button parameterSatzVergleich;
    private Button neuerParameter;
    private EditText filterparameternummer;
    private EditText filterinfotext;
    private int paramnummer;
    private String infotext;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.offlineparameter);

        this.dbHelper = DBHandler.getDBHelper();

        // Eabar: Ereignisse ausblenden per default
        findViewById(R.id.verbundenMit).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.DeviceName).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Buttons
        parameterSatzVergleich = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Parametersatzvergleich);
        parameterSatzVergleich.setOnClickListener(this);
        parameterSatzVergleich.setTextColor(-16777216);
        if (getCommunicationService() == null){
        parameterSatzVergleich.setTextColor(-3355444);//LTGRAY
        }
        neuerParameter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NeuParameter);
        neuerParameter.setOnClickListener(this);

        filterparameternummer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterParameternummer);
        filterinfotext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterInfotext);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DB_SOLLWERTE, true);


        this.listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ParameterSet>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {// Methode überschreiben
                ParameterSet item = getItem(position);

                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);// Ergebnis der originalmethode holen

                TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1); // manipulieren
                textView1.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.parameter_set_number, item.getParameterIndex() + 1));

                TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
                if (!item.isEmpty()) {// Version mit "leer" bezeichnen
                    String temp = (getResources().getString(R.string.parameter_set_version, item.getVersion()));
                    String temp2 = (getResources().getString(R.string.parameter_set_infotext, item.getInfoText()));
                    textView2.setText(temp + "     " + temp2);
                }
                else {
                    textView2.setText(R.string.parameter_set_empty);
                }

                return view;// zurückgeben
            }
        };

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.offline_parameter_list);
        listView.setAdapter(this.listAdapter);

        try {
            List<ParameterSet> parameterSets = this.dbHelper.selectAllParameterSets();
            OfflineParameterActivity.this.listAdapter.clear();
            OfflineParameterActivity.this.listAdapter.addAll(parameterSets); // Alle Parametersätze in den ArrayAdapter werfen
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: Parameterliste nicht erstellt", e);
        }

        // TODO: ist kein Eintrag passend:leere Listview! listView.setEmptyView(layout.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ParameterSet parameter = (ParameterSet) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(OfflineParameterActivity.this, ParameterDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(ParameterDetailsActivity.EXTRA_PARAMETER_ID, parameter.getID());
                String source = "offline_db";
                intent.putExtra(ParameterDetailsActivity.EXTRA_URSPRUNGSACTIVITY, source);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PARAMETER_DETAILS);
            }
        });

        // Parameternummer Text verändert
        this.filterparameternummer.addTextChangedListener(new AbstractTextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                OfflineParameterActivity.this.listAdapter.clear();
            }
        });
    }

    public void search(View view) {
        // hide Keyboard
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(filterparameternummer.getWindowToken(), 0);

        try {
            // Parameternummer filtern
            String nummer = filterparameternummer.getText().toString();
            if (nummer.equals("")) {
                this.paramnummer = -1;
            }
            else {
                this.paramnummer = Integer.parseInt(nummer)-1;
            }
            // Infotext
            this.infotext = filterinfotext.getText().toString();

            // Parametersätze auswählen
            List<ParameterSet> parameterSets = this.dbHelper.selectAllParameterSets(this.paramnummer, this.infotext);
            OfflineParameterActivity.this.listAdapter.clear();
            OfflineParameterActivity.this.listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            OfflineParameterActivity.this.listAdapter.addAll(parameterSets); // Alle Parametersätze in den ArrayAdapter werfen  
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error weil ebbes net gut isch", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PARAMETER_DETAILS) {
            finish();
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_ENABLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                startBluetoothDevicesActivity();
            }

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_DEVICES && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                final BluetoothDevice device = data.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE);
                Log.d(TAG, "Selected bluetooth device " + device);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle(1);
                extras.putParcelable(EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE, device);
                bindService(BluetoothService.class, extras);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        super.onServiceConnected(name, service);
        //EABAR
            TextView deviceName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DeviceName);
            deviceName.setText(getCommunicationService().getConnectedDeviceName());
            findViewById(R.id.verbundenMit).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.DeviceName).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        super.onServiceDisconnected(name);
        //EABAR: TODO: Wie bekomme ich mit wenn die Verbindung unterbrochen wird?
        findViewById(R.id.verbundenMit).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.DeviceName).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ActionBar / Menü
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.offlineparameter_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean isConnected = getCommunicationService() != null;

        if (isConnected) {
            setTitle("T12 Control - Offlineparameter - ONLINE");
        }
        else {
            setTitle("T12 Control - Offlineparameter");
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void startBluetoothDevicesActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BluetoothDevicesActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_DEVICES);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.Parametersatzvergleich) {
            if (v == parameterSatzVergleich) {
                if (getCommunicationService() == null){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "zuerst Verbindung zur T12 aufbauen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                else{
                    //TODO: Vergleich
                }
            }
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.NeuParameter) {
            if (v == neuerParameter) {
                if (filterparameternummer.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Parameternummer auswählen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else { 
                    int temp = Integer.parseInt(filterparameternummer.getText().toString());
                    if ( temp < 101 && temp > 0 ) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(OfflineParameterActivity.this, ParameterDetailsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ParameterDetailsActivity.EXTRA_PARAMETER_INDEX, Integer.parseInt(filterparameternummer.getText().toString()) - 1 );
                        intent.putExtra(ParameterDetailsActivity.EXTRA_URSPRUNGSACTIVITY, "offline_neu");
                        startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "zulässige Parameternummern von 1 bis 100 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    private static abstract class AbstractTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // Interessiert uns nicht
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Interessiert uns nicht
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add android:cacheColorHint attribute to ur listview

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Quick answer, but this has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

set cacheColorHint attribute as #00000000 to ur listview
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

Comment: Thanks for the response, but cacheColorHint does not seem to affect this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
listView.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Hope it helps.